# How to make div alignment to bottom in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make div alignment to bottom and in line I tried some answers given here but no luck ... here is my code but there is small gap in bottom of div one and div three how I can fix this ?

```css
.bg {
  background: gray;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc1 {
    margin-top: 325px;
  }
}

.bgc1 {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc2 {
    margin-top: 375px;
  }
}

.bgc2 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc3 {
    margin-top: 425px;
  }
}

.bgc3 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc4 {
    margin-top: 475px;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.bgc4 {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .rowd {
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg">
  <div class="row rowd">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse velit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. quis nostrud</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

sorry for my english..

Comment: So what are you asking? Is it the gray space you want gone, or the area that's around the text but still colored?

Comment: I just want to remove that little gray space under div One and div Two...

Comment: Alright. Thank you. One of the answers below should do it, but here's a hint: You'll want to work with 'margin', as that's what's causing the space inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this below css because `body` & `p` tag have default `margin`

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  background: gray;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc1 {
    margin-top: 325px;
  }
}

.bgc1 {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc2 {
    margin-top: 375px;
  }
}

.bgc2 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc3 {
    margin-top: 425px;
  }
}

.bgc3 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bgc4 {
    margin-top: 475px;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.bgc4 {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .rowd {
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg">
  <div class="row rowd">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse velit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. quis nostrud</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 bgc4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

**HTML**

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}

.bg {
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.bgc1, .bgc2, .bgc3, .bgc4 {
  color:white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.bgc1{
  background:black;
}

.bgc2 {
  background:red;
}

.bgc3 {
  background:green;
}

.bgc4 {
  background:blue;
}

.rowd {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg">
  <div class="row rowd">
    <div class="col-md-2 bgc1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse velit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 bgc2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. quis nostrud</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 bgc3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 bgc4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzfuw8a2/26/)

Comment: Div should come little down to previous div .. so I have to use top margin to bring it down.. I just want to remove that little gray space under div One and div Two...